# Memory loss using valgrind in c

Tags: c

I have a custom `struct` mystruct.

```
typedef struct mystruct
{
    int data;
    struct mystruct * parent;
    struct mystruct * child;
    struct mystruct * next;
}mystruct;
```

Now I am doing postorder traversal of this mystruct in a function `traverse()`

```
mystruct * create(mystruct * root)
{
    mystruct * newNode=malloc(sizeof(mystruct));
    //change some pointers like make newNode->parent=root->parent
    //
    //
    return newNode;
}

void traverse(mystruct * root)
{
 if(root==NULL)
    return;

 //here I am calling a new function 
 if() // somecondition
 {
    mystruct * newNode=create(root);
    root=NULL;
    free(root);
    root=newNode;
 }


 traverse(root->child);
 traverse(root->next);

}

void delete(mystruct * root)
{
    if(root==NULL)
        return;

    delete(root->child);
    delete(root->next);
    free(root);
}
```

Even after freeing my structure at the end, `valgrind` shows memory loss due to `newNode` being created. How can I remove these memory losses?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not very clear without full valgrind output, but here:

`root=NULL;
 free(root);
 root=newNode;`

You assigned `NULL` to root, then you freeing `NULL` what is totally pointless, and assigning new pointer to root. So old value of root pointer is lost and you have no way to free that memory. Consider removing `root=NULL`.